# Necessary to make periods from the lines

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapreduce

We have

```
let range = [
  '2022-11-19',
  '2022-11-26',
  '2022-12-03',
  '2022-12-10',
  '2022-12-17',
  '2022-12-19'
]
```

we need to get

```
let ranger = [
  {'2022-11-19': '2022-11-26'},
  {'2022-11-26': '2022-12-03'},
  {'2022-12-03': '2022-12-10'},
  {'2022-12-10': '2022-12-17'},
  {'2022-12-17': '2022-12-19'}
]
```

I tried to do it through map, but it turned out to be some kind of crap

Answer (score 1):

You can slice the array before mapping.

```js
let range = [
  '2022-11-19',
  '2022-11-26',
  '2022-12-03',
  '2022-12-10',
  '2022-12-17',
  '2022-12-19'
];
let o = range.slice(1).map((x, i)=>({[range[i]]: x}));
console.log(o);
```